# Receiving IActionResult from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created Web API, and my problem is reading results from it to client.

WebApi method which creating user:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostNewUser([FromBody]UserDto userDto)
{
    if (userDto == null)
        return BadRequest(nameof(userDto));
    IUsersService usersService = GetService<IUsersService>();
    var id = usersService.Add(userDto);
    return Created("api/users/", id.ToString());
}
```

And the client which want to call API code is:

```
public int CreateUser(UserDto dto)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string endpoint = ApiQuery.BuildAddress(Endpoints.Users);
        var json = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var postReult = client.PostAsync(endpoint, json).Result;
        return 1; //?? 
    }
}
```

It works, response gives *201 (Created)* but I have no idea how to return correct result, which should be:

```
/api/users/id_of_created_user
```

I'm using netcore2.0 in both projects

Comment: When you have postResult, you should first check its IsSuccessStatusCode property and then read the Content in one way or another (like calling ReadStreamAsync() for example). I would also recommend using async / await all the way avoiding calling Result on a returned Task.

Comment: you mean something like this ? `var result = await postReult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: currently what you received in `var postReult`?

Comment: the problem is that if i get postRestul.Content.ReadAsAnything()
it doesnt give me 'api/users/newUserId' - it gives me only newUserId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Web API either construct the created location URL manually

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostNewUser([FromBody]UserDto userDto) {
    if (userDto == null)
        return BadRequest(nameof(userDto));
    IUsersService usersService = GetService<IUsersService>();
    var id = usersService.Add(userDto);
    //construct desired URL
    var url = string.Format("api/users/{0}",id.ToString());
    return Created(url, id.ToString());
}
```

Or use one of the `CreateAt*` overloads

```
//return 201 created status code along with the 
//controller, action, route values and the actual object that is created
return CreatedAtAction("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = id }, id.ToString());

//OR 

//return 201 created status code along with the 
//route name, route value, and the actual object that is created
return CreatedAtRoute("RouteName", new { id = id }, id.ToString());
```

In the client, the location is retrieved from the header of the response.

```
status HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async Task<int> CreateUser(UserDto dto) {
    string endpoint = ApiQuery.BuildAddress(Endpoints.Users);
    var json = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var postResponse = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, json);

    var location = postResponse.Headers.Location;// api/users/{id here}

    var id = await postResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>();

    return id;
}
```

You also appear to be sending the id as part of the response which can be retrieved from the response content.

Note the refactoring of `HttpClient` to avoid creating an instance every time which can lead to socked exhaustion that can cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can always return JsonResult and return JSON object from the server with required data for the client. Here is an example to use

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2ed7ae/jsonresult-type-in-mvc/